Is it possible to launch a Spring Batch job inside another job?
I have a Spring project where jobs are defined via XML files. I need to modify Job A so that, at a certain point when a specific condition is met, all the steps of another Job B are executed.
I tried linking Job B into Job A directly in the XML, but it didn't work. I also tried doing it in Java code by creating a tasklet in Job A that is responsible for launching Job B, but this resulted in an error. From what I understand, Spring doesn't allow a running job to launch another job.
Is there a way to achieve the desired behavior, or do I need to replicate all the tasklets from Job B in the XML file for Job A?
I tried to do something like this.
@Component
public class TaskletInsertedIntoJobA implements Tasklet {
  private final JobLauncher jobLauncher;

  private final Job secondaryJob;

  public TaskletInsertedIntoJobA(
      JobLauncher jobLauncher, @Qualifier("jobB") Job secondaryJob) {
    this.jobLauncher = jobLauncher;
    this.secondaryJob = secondaryJob;
  }

  @Override
  public RepeatStatus execute(StepContribution contribution,
      ChunkContext chunkContext) throws Exception {
    JobParameters jobParameters = new JobParametersBuilder();

    // Logic for setting job parameters

    // Run job B
    JobExecution jobExecution = jobLauncher.run(secondaryJob, jobParameters);

    if (jobExecution.getStatus().isUnsuccessful()) {
      throw new RuntimeException("Secondary job failed!");
    }

    return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
  }
}

At the end of job B, of course, job A should continue with the execution of the remaining steps.

You can use a JobStep for that. This is a step implementation that delegates the execution to a job. With that, you can design jobs of jobs, rather than duplicating steps from job B to job A.
